# How do I deserialize an AWS API Gateway + Lambda response in my Swift App?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS Lambda function that does the following:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Logic
    return json.dumps({"name": "foo", "job": "bar"})
```

And an AWS API Gateway endpoint that integrates with the above Lambda via GET method. When I make a cURL to the Gateway endpoint, it works fine:

```
$ curl https://my-aws-gateway-endpoint/stage/endpoint

"{\"name\": \"foo\", \"job\": \"bar\"}"
```

However, when I make the same request in my Swift app, I get the following error:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

This is how I'm making the request:

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
var data: Data // This is a struct that contains the fields "name" and "job"
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            defer { semaphore.signal() }

            if let _ = error {
                return
            }

            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                print("Invalid response: \(response?.description ?? "")")
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                print("No data received")
                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                songData = try decoder.decode(Data.self, from: jsonData)
            } catch {
                print(error)
                return
            }
}

task.resume()
semaphore.wait()

return data
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `[String:String].self` instead of `Data.self`. With `var songData: [String:String]...`. Note there is no need for the `let jsonData = try ....`, use `data` directly

Comment: Also, use `Codable` with `JSONDecoder` rather than `JSONSerialization`

Comment: good point, and use Swift concurrency framework (async/await) instead of code from the Dark Ages.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something more modern, such as in this example code:

```
struct SongModel: Codable {
    let name, job: String
}

var mySong: SongModel?
Task {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://my-aws-gateway-endpoint/stage/endpoint") {
        mySong = await doRequest(url: url)
    }
}

 func doRequest(url: URL) async -> SongModel? {
     do {
         let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
         guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
               (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
             print("Invalid response: \(response.description)")
             return nil
         }
         return try JSONDecoder().decode(SongModel.self, from: data)
     } catch {
         print(error)
         return nil
     }
 }
```